# select all on focus in lots of jTextField

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, selectall

I have lots of jTextFields in my application (About 34 jTextFields) and I want all of them select all of their text when get focus and select none of text on focus lost.
Is there any way to do this with one listener or should I write a "FocusGained" and a "FocusLost" for each of these 34 jTextFields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create on class and extend the JTextField now implement whatever you want in this class. And where you can create object of JTextField like this

```
JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
frm.add(txt1);
```

instead of do this way

```
JTextField txt1 = new CustomText();
frm.add(txt1);
```

so you have to set the common class for the Text field

Answer (score 12):

Create a class for this task:

```
static class FocusTextField extends JTextField {
    {
        addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                FocusTextField.this.select(0, getText().length());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                FocusTextField.this.select(0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Example usage (code below):

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

    frame.add(new FocusTextField());
    frame.add(new FocusTextField());
    frame.add(new FocusTextField());
    frame.add(new FocusTextField());
    frame.add(new FocusTextField());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to do this with one listener

You can use the KeyboardFocusManager. See the example from [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/).

Answer (score -1):

I would say the easy way to do it is add an action on click that simply selects all

```
private void jTextField1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.selectAll();
}
```

Comment: This does not cover all the other ways that a text field may get selected: Tabbing, Alt-Tabbing, by Swing/AWT call.